# Meaning of (\x y z -> x y z) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda

In understand the meaning and the type of `(\x y z -> x+y+z)` for example. The type of `(\x y z -> x y z)`is `(t1 -> t2 -> t3) -> t1 -> t2 -> t3`. But what does that mean and why are now round brackets in the type?

Comment: Because the first parameter `x` is a function `t1 -> t2 -> t3`. `(->)` is right associative, so `a -> b -> c` is `a -> (b -> c)`. The brackets are thus necessary to interpret `(t1 -> t2 -> t3) -> (t1 -> (t2 -> t3))` instead `t1 -> (t2 -> (t3 -> (t1 -> (t2 -> t3))))`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So the function x is simply applied to y and z and you could write x y z directly ?

Comment: @AnnaSaabel If `f` is defined as `\x y z -> x y z`, then `f x y z` is the same as `x y z`.

Comment: `x y z` is equivalent to `(x y) z` because of the left-associative nature of function application. Function application is *not* fully associative like `(+)`. `x + y + z == (x + y) + z == x + (y + z)`, but `(x y) z /= x (y z)` in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Haskell, something of the form `a b c` (i.e., juxtaposition of letter-names without infix symbols between them) generally means `a` is a *function* and being applied to `b` and `c`.
In this case, `x y z` is basically what in other languages would be written `x(y,z)`. In Haskell, you can also write it

```
\x y z -> x(y)(z)
```

or in fact `(x)(y)(z)` or `((x)y)z`, but parentheses are discouraged unless needed.

So knowing that, it's clear that the type of the first argument of that lambda, i.e. of `x`, needs to be a function type. In this case, a function taking two arguments of whatever type `y` and `z` happen to be, respectively. I.e.

```
(\x y z -> x y z) :: (typeofy -> typeofz -> resulttype) -> ...
                     └───────── type of x ────────────┘
```

Now say `y :: t1` and `z :: t2` and the final result should be `t3`, and we have

```
(\x y z -> x y z) :: (t1 -> t2 -> t3) -> (t1 -> t2 -> t3)
                     └─ type of x ──┘     └y    └z    └(x y z)
```

Function-arrows are right-associative, i.e. the parentheses on the right side of the type can be omitted:

```
(\x y z -> x y z) :: (t1 -> t2 -> t3) -> t1 -> t2 -> t3
                     └─ type of x ──┘    └y    └z    └(x y z)
```

The parentheses on the left can *not* be omitted: `t1->t2->t3 -> t1->t2->t3` would actually parse as `t1->(t2->(t3->(t1->(t2->t3))))`. That would be instead the type of

```
(\w x y w' x' -> y) :: t1 -> t2 -> t3 -> t1 -> t2 -> t3
                       └w    └x    └y    └w'   └x'   └y
```

...preferrably written `(\_ _ y _ _ -> y)`.